# Gtk warning after ugrading to yosemite

Tags: pygtk

I am trying to run a program written in python on my mac (Yosemite). 
Almost immediately after starting the program it gives me the following error:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
```

[edit] tried to isolate the issue, the error appears upon entering

```
Adriaan$ ipython --gui=gtk
Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov  5 2014, 15:41:54) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 2.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

(process:969): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
```

I have tried reinstalling X11(v2.7.7) and rebooting. (as listed in similar threads). 
Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Comment: It's not an error, but a warning. If your program runs fine, you can ignore it (but yes, it can be resolved, by setting your locale, in your `.bashrc` or similar).

Comment: The program is not running fine (no gui shows up). How do i set the locale in .bashrc ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Xquartz.app first.  Then:

```
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from matplotlib import pyplot
```

Generally works for me after each OS upgrade.