# Cant open display: Gtk-WARNING for Gdis program on Yosemite mac os x

Tags: gtk, warnings, osx-yosemite

I am quite new to mac and I am not sure what to do to resolve the problem.

Let me explain.

I am trying to use Gdis on mac ( there is already an executable for it)
http://sourceforge.net/projects/gdis/

When I double click on the executable nothing shows up on the screen.

So I go to gdis.log file and I see this error:
(gdis:56038): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.LqpuLdwkGW/org.macosforge.xquartz:0

then I do ls -l at the file and I see:
srw-rw-rw-  1 name  name  0B Nov 29 17:14 /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.LqpuLdwkGW/org.macosforge.xquartz:0=

The file is 0B ??

I have read people had this problem when they upgraded to yosemite and they had to reinstall xcode and xquartz.

My machine has just a brand new installation of yosemite and I installed both xcode and xquartz.

I have found a few thread but none of them are helping:
["Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:" when running a gtkmm project in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745740/gtk-warning-cannot-open-display-when-running-a-gtkmm-project-in-eclipse)

this one being helpful but can t find the Run Configuration in my install.

also this one but there are no correct answer for this one [Gtk warning after ugrading to yosemite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26840889/gtk-warning-after-ugrading-to-yosemite)

when i check my env I have DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.LqpuLdwkGW/org.macosforge.xquartz:0

Same as the gtk warning

Any idea please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this might not be the cleanest answer, but I think the gdis executable is not working on yosemite and you have to recompile it yourself.

The reason I say that is I installed inkscape and that worked fine so the problem was not from xquartz.

So I first installed Mac port from their website: https://www.macports.org/install.php

From mac port I installed:
cvs and perl.

Then I went to gdis website and download the develoment version: http://gdis.sourceforge.net/download.html following the instructions.

When you try to compile it there will be some missing libraries.

So with mac port you need to install:

pkgconfig, gtk2 and gtkglext

and that should work. (also I recommend answering yes to Build an OS-X app bundle? question so you get a gdis.app at the end.

hope that can help someone who is trying to use gdis .

Cheers